# How do I build an API for my Rails app, so that multiple sites can share one database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I have a Rails application that right now is pretty standard: Heroku/PostgreSQL backend, users go directly to my site to update data, there's no mobile app or anything. We're going to start licensing out the tech to other companies, so that different versions of the interface live on company1.mywebsite.com, company2.mywebsite.com, etc, where all of these interfaces share the same database.

I want some advice on how to go about building this. Do I create a separate Rails app for company1, company2, etc (with a lot of redundant code) and then set up each of them with API keys to query my master app, using its RESTful routes?

Any tutorials to point me to would be great as well.

Comment: It sounds like you want some sort of multi tenancy on your application? Can you give us an idea of what type of data your working with? Would it be possible for you to create a company object that holds a subdomain name and is the parent object for the rest of the objects in the db assoicated with that company?

Comment: The data is mostly just text, the application is a discussion forum. What you're saying makes sense to me - I guess the issue would be how to customize the views for different company interfaces? I imagine it could get bulky with a lot of if user.companyname == "TKTK", show this, else, show this

Comment: We have a similar setup, but we use different domain names for different companies. We initialize the current company in a before filter in application controller using domain name and have a config file which defines what theme to use for which company. We use less.js to define most of common styles which can be reused and abstract out differences in a small theme file. To get the posts of a current company, we do something like current_company.posts

Comment: Yeah, it could get bulky if you are not careful. I would limit the changeable attributes like company name and related fields and use css themes to your advantage. You could set up custom themes and allow companies to upload their own using paperclip and store the preference in the company object.

Comment: You might take a look at the SaaS kit from http://www.railskits.com. I'm using this guy's code for multi-tenancy in two apps. He really knows his stuff, keeps it updated regularly, and it is very good, clean code. With an already-established app you might not want to re-build into his kit, but you could certainly see how he does it and learn from that. IMHO it provides a textbook approach to doing this well, and would be well-worth the $250 you spend to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you the book Service Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails, by Paul Dix. It has a lot of info about the kind of system that you want to build.

To answer your question:

- Build an API server. It serves a JSON – for example – RESTful interface.

  ```
  api.mydomain/client1/users.json
  ```
- Build a frontend server. It consume the API service – using typhoeus for example – and serves the final pages. It uses a subdomain or domain name for identification of different clients.

  ```
  client1.mydomain/users
  ```

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar "platform".

What we did:

1. build a master API app (REST + Push)
2. build a core plugin for rails which has all the shared code
3. build a separate rails app for each client which has all the client specific code

We are using this setup for 3 years now and I'm pretty happy with it.